# Saving 2 player values in a Roblox leaderboard

Tags: lua, datastore, leaderboard

I have been trying to save 2 values for a game that I'm working on, and I Can't get the script to work for some reason.

Here is the script -

```
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local DataStoreService = game:GetService("DataStoreService")

local SufferingsStore = DataStoreService:GetDataStore("Sufferings")
local SufferCoinsStore = DataStoreService:GetDataStore("SufferCoins")

local function leaderboard(player)
local leaderstats = Instance.new("Folder")
leaderstats.Name = "leaderstats"
leaderstats.Parent = player

local SufferCoins = Instance.new("IntValue")
SufferCoins.Name = "SufferCoins"
SufferCoins.Parent = leaderstats

local Sufferings = Instance.new("IntValue")
Sufferings.Name = "Sufferings"
Sufferings.Parent = leaderstats

local data1, data2
local success, errorMessage = pcall(function()
    data1 = SufferCoinsStore:GetAsync(player.UserId.. "-SufferCoins")
    data2 = SufferingsStore:GetAsync(player.UserId.. "-Sufferings")
end)

if success then
    SufferCoins.Value = data1
    Sufferings.Value = data2
    print("Data succesfuly loaded for " .. player.Name)
else
    warn(errorMessage)
end
end

local function saveData(player)
local success, errorMessage = pcall(function()
    SufferCoinsStore:SetAsync(player.UserId.. "-SufferCoins", player.leaderstats.SufferCoins.Value)
    SufferingsStore:SetAsync(player.UserId.. "-Sufferings", player.leaderstats.Sufferings.Value)
end)

if success then
    print("Data Saved for " .. player.Name)
else
    print("An Error Occurred While Saving for " .. player.Name)
    warn(errorMessage)
end
end

Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
leaderboard(player)

player.CharacterAdded:Connect(function()
    leaderboard(player)
end)
end)

Players.PlayerRemoving:Connect(function(player)
saveData(player)
end)

for _, player in pairs(Players:GetPlayers()) do
leaderboard(player)
end
```

I tried watching Youtube Tutorials, asking ChatGPT(it was helpful once) and I hoped the Data would save. The script ended up not doing much, only printing out that it loaded / saved the data without actualy doing so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this and make sure that Roblox API Services are on, okey instead of doing a lot of functions for call the load and save data, you could use PlayerRemoving and PlayerAdded, and create your variables for the leaderstats, so maybe that's the problem, or you could use this code instead:

```
local player = game:GetService("Players")
local dataStore = game:GetService("DataStoreService")

local SufferingsDataStore = dataStore:GetDataStore("Sufferings")
local SufferCoinsDataStore = dataStore:GetDataStore("SufferCoins")

player.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(plr)
    print(plr.Name .." joined")
    
    local folder = Instance.new("Folder", plr)
    folder.Name = "leaderstats"
    
    local Sufferings = Instance.new("IntValue", folder)
    Sufferings.Name = "Sufferings"
    Sufferings.Value = 0

    local SufferCoins = Instance.new("IntValue", folder)
    SufferCoins.Name = "SufferCoins"
    SufferCoins.Value = 0

    local infoSaved = nil
    local infoSaved2 = nil

    local succeful, fail = pcall(function()
        infoSaved = SufferingsDataStore:GetAsync(plr.UserId)
        infoSaved2 = SufferCoinsDataStore:GetAsync(plr.UserId)
    end)

    if succeful then
        plr.leaderstats.Sufferings.Value = infoSaved
        plr.leaderstats.SufferCoins.Value = infoSaved2
        warn("Data loaded successfully")
    end
end)

player.PlayerRemoving:Connect(function(plrE)
    warn("Goodbye " ..plrE.Name.."!")
    local points1 = plrE.leaderstats.SufferCoins.Value
    local points2 = plrE.leaderstats.Sufferings.Value

    local succeful, fail = pcall(function()
        SufferingsDataStore:SetAsync(plrE.UserId, points2)
        SufferCoinsDataStore:SetAsync(plrE.UserId, points1)
    end)

    if succeful then
        warn("Data saved correctly")
    end
end)
```

Create and order your variables, then copy and paste infoSaved many times as you want, then just set the infoSaved to the datastore get async inside the pcall, also set variables to infoSaved for load it `plr.leaderstats.Sufferings.Value = infoSaved` when player removing do the same with `points1` set points to `plr.leaderstats.yourValue.value`, also set async data with points.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**